# What causes "system cannot find the file specified" with Runtime.exec? (assoc/ftype)

Tags: java, exec

Does anyone know why these two statements result in the shown exception?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("assoc .vlan=\"file type description\"");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ftype \"file type description\"=" + System.getProperty("user.home")+ "\\folder 1\\folder 2\\my executable.exe\" /inject \"%1\"");
```

And Here's the Exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "assoc": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
```

All right, I've changed this but still the association is not made whereas the very same command is executable and working under the cmd command prompt.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c assoc .vlan=\"file type description\"");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c ftype \"file type description\"=\"" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\folder 1\\folder 2\\my executable.exe\" /inject \"%1\"");
```

Any complementary suggestion?  Thank you!

Comment: `exec("assoc .vlan=\"file type description\"");` If that is making a file association, note that [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) is able to add file associations for an app.  Further, it can do it on Windows, OS X & *nix.  See the [demo. of the file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) for ..demo and downloadable source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it turns out, `assoc` and `ftype` are built-in shell commands and NOT executable files.  The same is true for `copy`, `dir`, etc.  What you can do instead is launch `cmd.exe` using the `/c` parameter to pass a command line string, e.g. `cmd.exe /c assoc ...`.

Comment: Thank you for your spot on answer, it got rid of the exception but the association does not happen when launched this way, however, when the same routine is run on command prompt it works just fine!  Please comment!

Comment: If you are running on Windows Vista or higher, those commands require elevated privileges (as they end up writing to the registry); otherwise you'll see "Access denied" errors. Capture the error code using `waitFor` on the `Process` object that the `exec()` call returns.  You'll probably see that it is non-zero (perhaps 5 indicating access denied).

Comment: Spot on!  Thank you a billion!  Now as my final question!  How would it be possible to run these commands in elevated mode??!  I haven't done that before!

Comment: Simplest case, but generally bad for usability: you force the user to start your app elevated -- then anything you do would be elevated by default. Slightly better: use an appropriate manifest setting to have an automatic request for elevation when your app starts (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx ) -- this would require a separately compiled EXE, though, and would not work well for a typical Java app.

Comment: More options: you request elevation for just the operations that need it in a "just in time" fashion. This requires a way to do the equivalent of ShellExecute ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/bb762153.aspx ), passing the "runas" verb to prompt for elevation. Or you could implement an NT service process that you can communicate with to do higher privilege actions (obviously this is a bit of a security hole unless you properly lock down the communication channel between your app and this service) -- probably not that easy in Java and much more complicated. Etc. Etc.

Comment: But how can we incorporate ShellExecute in the context of java?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5867/discussion-between-bobbymcr-and-sam)